# Reenable MenuItem in Async Callback

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, menuitem

So I have an **Android** *activity* with three **tab-fragments**, each with a **listview**, two of which house what is basically an *RSS* feed populated with an **async** call.

There is a menu button, id `action_refresh`, which calls each fragment's individual `refresh()` method. These methods clear the `List` of objects populating the list, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the custom **adapter**, then they call the **async** method `GetVideoFeed()`:

```
    private void refresh() {
        if (episodes.size() > 1){
            episodes.clear();
            episodeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        new GetVideoFeed().execute("http://www.example.org/podcast-video.xml");

    }
```

A similar method is used for the other *fragment*.

The `action_refresh` button calls this:

```
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        // Disable the action
        item.setEnabled(false);
        // Call refresh on the fragments
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        for(Fragment x :getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
            if (x instanceof PodcastFragment) {
                ((PodcastFragment) x).refresh();
            }
            if (x instanceof StoryFragment) {
                ((StoryFragment) x).refresh();
            }
            if (x instanceof DownloadFragment) {
                ((DownloadFragment) x).refresh();
            }

        }
        // Somehow enable this after async call...
        item.setEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
```

My problem lies in that the user might click refresh multiple times before the **async** method finishes, and so the `ListView` gets populated multiple times. I would like to **reenable** the menu `item` on the **callback**, but the async thread won't modify the main thread, and I don't know how to access the menu item outside of the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, though I suspect there in lies the solution.

So my question is, in a nut shell, how do I **reenable** a `MenuItem` from an async **callback**, and what should I do if there are *two* such callbacks (and so this *reenabling* must be done when the final callback is complete)?

Answer (score 1):

The execute method should have onSuccess and onFailure callbacks.

Then you should implement those methods on each fragment and let the activity know (using a listener interface) that the execute method finished.

The activity should implement the interface and when all the fragments have informed that were done executing, just call invalidateOptionsMenu.

The onCreateOptionsMenu should enable or disable the refresh menu item depending if all the fragments informed that were done executing.

Hope you get the idea or let me know if you need a sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but what do you mean by onSuccess callbacks? I use a onPostExecute callback, should I listen for this in the parent activity? And this would be what kind of listener? onPostExecuteListener?

Comment: Callbacks are methods called when an asynchronous operation finishes. I am not sure what ```GetVideoFeed``` class has inside, maybe you can edit and add the code to your original post. Since you mentioned onPostExecute method, I am assuming that you are using an AsyncTask object. On that method (onPostExecute) you should inform your activity that it has finished doing that task (by using an interface listener defined in the fragment, see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). When all the fragments informed the activity, you can call invalidateOptionsMenu.